# can bundler install gems from a bare git repo?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

So, reading http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Public-Access, I'm trying to setup a bare repo as instructed on a simple http server (no git-daemon, do I need one?).

My gem has a gemname.gemspec in the root and all seems well.

On using a Gemfile with:

```
gem 'gemname', :git => 'http://path'
```

Ok, then

```
> bundle install
...
Installing blah...
Using gemname (1.0.0) from source at 'http://path'
...
```

and all seems well, until I list the gems and 'gemname' isn't there.  Require also fails.

So then, plan #2: since we mirror the server as paths, I figure I'll use a direct path to the gem without the git repo:

```
gem 'gemname', :path => 'path/to_gemname'
```

again, bundler says ok.

```
Using gemname (1.0.0) from source at 'path/to_gemname'
```

but again, doesn't install it or reference it correctly from within the app.

Any idea on how this should work (i.e. proper directory layout, etc.) or do I need a real git/gem server to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Bundler.setup`](http://gembundler.com/bundler_setup.html) first.

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

require "gemname"

# use gemname
```

You might also find it useful to call `Bundler.require`. This will require all gems in the Gemfile automagically. No need to call `require "gem name"` for every gem you use.

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

Bundler.require

# use any gem in Gemfile
```

Also have a look at this similar answer, which provides a more sophisticated version of the above code: [Bundler isn't loading gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170697/bundler-isnt-loading-gems#answer-2214441)

You can check if everything worked by typing `bundle list` in a command line window. You should see something like the following.

```
$ bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.1.3)
  * some_dependency (0.0.1)
  * gemname (1.2.3 <git-sha-hash>)
```

Comment: oh nice, that worked! Thanks!  OH! Now I get it... doh! It's right there on the Bundler page, but I'm used to Rails doing this bit for me... needless to say this wasn't a rails app, so I had to do it manually.  Thanks! (doh!)

Comment: I also had a lot of these moments :) for example i spent a long time figuring out why 5.days.from.now didnt work when i first used the Time class outside a rails app...